# WebRTC Chrome microphone not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, microphone

## Description

**Specs**: Chrome version 44,45,46 both Win, Mac and Linux.

**Actions made:**

1. first source: camera and microphone granted via getUserMedia
2. second source: microphone only granted via getUserMedia
3. both sources are stored in JS object
4. volume level checked with WebAudio (getting peak level over 5 seconds) 3) WebRTC call
5. established within a first source

**Symptoms:**

1. volume level is detected as 0
2. in the WebRTC call one user doesn't hear the Chrome user

**Expected behavior:**

1. volume level is detected higher than 0
2. in the WebRTC call both users hear each other

**Severity:** often, but not always. Doesn't seem to be tied to particular user, it happens from day to day with any user.

**(!)** Can *sometimes* be temporary fixed by restarting Chrome completely.

**(!)** Can *sometimes* be temporary fixed on Mac (until restart):

1. Go to Mac Applications > Utilities > Terminal
2. Copy and paste this command, then press Enter: sudo killall VDCAssistant
3. Type in your computer password and press Enter
4. Restart Chrome

**(!)** Happened even with the only one source requested.

## Help

This seems to be a massive issue addressed to Google a long time ago, but still not solved. Have anyone faced it? Is there any way to fix this in JavaScript or anyhow else?

## Edit 1

It is also reproducible at https://apprtc.appspot.com/ and any other webrtc websites.

## Edit 2

Seems like it is WebRTC bug:

- https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4799
- https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5175

Comment: Have you tried without webaudio? You can still control the playback volume with audio/video element. Which is the default input audio device?

Comment: I didn't try without webaudio. It is difficult to say which one is default as I don't have access to customers' computers. Usually it is "built in" one. I can control the playback, but can I control microphone output volume like this?

Comment: In both Mac and Windows you can easily find out which is the default one. You cannot control the microphone level without webaudio and there's more like gain. I personally believe that from UX standpoint, the remote parties should be able to control the volume level themselves.

Comment: The issue is not about volume, it is a bug, the microphone is just not working - it doesn't send any sound over webrtc and also cannot be detected via webaudio. Are you sure you understood the issue correctly?

Comment: If I got correctly, you're opening a WebRTC connection with two sources selected (and both are using the same audio device) You didn't mentioned if this is done by one party or two different ones (and on two different machines or only one). But you said that the issue is reproducible even with only one. I never had this problem and I was using different audio devices: internal mic, external mic, line-in, line-in from sound card, stereo mix etc. How do you know that the volume is 0? Are you using a audio or video tag and attach the stream to it?

Comment: By mistake, I added my comment as an answer. But my questions still stands. How do you know that volume is 0? Are you using an audio/video tag?

Comment: I answered in the question you deleted. I am pre-checking volume with WebAudio. In the actual video call I do use video and audio tags, the symptom is that there is no sound going from Chrome user.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script I have in my `.profile` that will resolve this issue:

```
alias fixcam="sudo kill -9 `pgrep VDCAssistant`; sudo killall coreaudiod"
```

Then I just run `fixcam` from terminal. If you add the above command to your `.profile` you'll need to open a new terminal window or run `source ~/.profile` to reload the configuration.

It looks like the bug has been isolated to `coreaudiod` getting in a bad state. I haven't tested ONLY restarting `coreaudiod` but it's possible that will work also.

Comment: vdcassistant is for the "my camera does not work anymore" case

Comment: @PhilippHancke Although that is for cameras, i've had it fix mics too (mainly where skype isn't properly releasing control)